# when i send a image from cameraStream to native(java),the app will Lost connection to device

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

I develop with dart&java, when i send a image Data from cameraStream, to native(java),the app will stop, actually it's dark screen and pause there. And the log show "Lost connection to device". it's happen at camera ResolutionPreset is medium and high . low quality it's working but cant use because image it's too small and low quality.
at last thanks for help. :)

code :

```
 @override


void initState() {
// TODO: implement initState
super.initState();
if(widget.cameras == null  || widget.cameras.length < 1){
    print("No Cameara is found");
}else{
  onCameraSelected(widget.cameras[0]);
}
```

}

```
void onCameraSelected(CameraDescription description)async{
controller = CameraController(description, ResolutionPreset.medium);
controller.addListener((){
  if(mounted)setState(() {

  });
  if(controller.value.hasError){
    print("camera error :${controller.value.errorDescription}");
  }
});

controller.initialize().then((_){
  if(!mounted){
    return;
  }
  setState(() {

  });

  controller.startImageStream((CameraImage image){
    if(! isDetecting){
      isDetecting = true;
      CameraImage imageStream = image;

      Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)).then((_){
        FlutterPlugin.jump(
            bytesList: imageStream.planes.map((plane){
              return plane.bytes;
            }).toList()
            ,width: imageStream.width,
            height: imageStream.height
            ,numResults: 2,
            ratio:( imageStream.width / imageStream.height));
      });




    }

  });

});
```

log info:

```
E/flutter ( 6983): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: CameraException(No camera is streaming images, stopImageStream was called when no camera is streaming images.)
E/flutter ( 6983): #0 CameraController.stopImageStream (package:camera/camera.dart:397:7)
E/flutter ( 6983): 
E/flutter ( 6983): #1 _MyHomePageState.onCameraSelected.. (package:flutter_decode_qr_demo_1/main.dart:127:24)
E/flutter ( 6983): #2 _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1120:38)
E/flutter ( 6983): #3 _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
E/flutter ( 6983): #4 _FutureListener.handleWhenComplete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:150:18)
E/flutter ( 6983): #5 Future._propagateToListeners.handleWhenCompleteCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:609:39)
E/flutter ( 6983): #6 Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:665:37)
E/flutter ( 6983): #7 Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:473:7)
E/flutter ( 6983): #8 new Future.delayed. (dart:async/future.dart:313:16)
E/flutter ( 6983): #9 _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1120:38)
E/flutter ( 6983): #10 _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
E/flutter ( 6983): #11 _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:923:7)
E/flutter ( 6983): #12 _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded. (dart:async/zone.dart:963:23)
E/flutter ( 6983): #13 _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
E/flutter ( 6983): #14 _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
E/flutter ( 6983): #15 _CustomZone.bindCallback. (dart:async/zone.dart:947:23)
E/flutter ( 6983): #16 Timer._createTimer. (dart:async/runtime/libtimer_patch.dart:21:15)
E/flutter ( 6983): #17 _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:382:19)
E/flutter ( 6983): #18 _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:416:5)
E/flutter ( 6983): #19 _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:171:12)
E/flutter ( 6983):
Lost connection to device.
```

Comment: In some situation this error will occured when you need to ask user for some permission to access some device feature or privacy. So try to grant this permission manually from your "App Info" and test it. This may solve your problem

Comment: @ParthPatel  thanks for your reply. and i dont know which permission need grant to.Besides if its permission's problem,why i can transmit camera stream data which is low quality?  :)  and thank you again.